# Error deploying ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

i tried deploy my ruby app in my server, but keeps me showing i am using 1.9.3  but i am not, on my server and computer the only version  have is 2.2.1, i never mention 1.9.3 in my app or server, someone can give me a help?

i found in : /var/lib/gems 2 folders: 1.8 and 1.9.1 i dont know if is relation for that.

```
DEBUG [f4634e5c]    Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@: bundle exit status: 18
bundle stdout: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 18
bundle stdout: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deploy@: bundle exit status: 18
bundle stdout: Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1
bundle stderr: Nothing written

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.1 (2015-02-26 patchlevel 85) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
```

Comment: First question is, what are you deploying to? Passenger, Puma,... Webrick...?

Comment: i am new on ror, but i am using Capistrano and unicorn

Comment: Check the first line in `/usr/bin/unicorn_rails` on your server. It should reference the Ruby executable it is using.

Comment: i edit my post again can u read?i found in : /var/lib/gems 2 folders: 1.8 and 1.9.1 i dont know if is relation for that, in unicorn i opened: unicorn_rails_1 and inside i just have that line: olddoc_placeholder

Comment: I might be off in my path, but... `/etc/init.d/unicorn` should reference a script should refer to something like `/usr/bin/unicorn_rails` or `/usr/local/bin/unicorn` or something like that; that file in turn should have as its first line `#!/path/to/ruby` or `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. If the former, you have found your rogue ruby. If the latter, execute `env ruby` to find it. (All of this on the server, not on your local.) Your output ("RubyGems Environment") does not help, as you haven't specified where it comes from or what command you obtained it with. Same with "in unicorn i opened"... no path